# Compile ANTLR generated code with C runtime on IBM mainframe (z/OS) using Metal C

Tags: c, antlr, antlr3, mainframe, zos

I'm looking to run a parser generated by ANTLR 3.5.2 on an IBM mainframe under zOS. I don't need to run ANTLR itself on the mainframe.  But I do need to be able to run the C code that ANTLR generates on the mainframe along with ANTLR's C runtime.  My question is really about how compatible gnu C is with Metal C for ANTLR's C runtime.

Either a positive or negative experience porting the C runtime to Metal C would help me assess the difficulty of this task.
Thanks very much.

Comment: Why use the metal option?  That's for applications where you specifically don't want to use Language Environment, e.g. in a JES exit.  LE is ubiquitous in the "normal" application space.  Why can't you just use the C runtime provided by LE?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I'm new to mainframes. I wasn't aware of the LE option.  Metal C was recommended to me.  But I'll check to see whether it's necessary for the project.  Do you know if anyone has run ANTLR generated C code on LE?

Comment: I do not.  Try browsing through the documentation and see if it conforms to the standards ANTLR requires.  It looks to be C11 compliant, among others.  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbc/cbc.htm

Comment: We're making progress with LE.  I'll post a summary of what we did if we get everything working.

Comment: We've been able to compile an link an ANTLR3 generated parser in C on z/OS. However, now we'd like it to work properly in an EBCDIC environment.  How can we go about doing this?  Where do we set the encoding to ANTLR3_ENC_EBCDIC?  Do we need to create a new string template?  Has anyone already done this?